# imagezilla api Failed

Tags: html, api

I'm trying to create a page that uploads an image to imagezilla using their api, but having no luck. Below is the code i'm using, but without the apikey, username and password for obvious reasons

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://imagezilla.net/api.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="passwordmd5" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="testmode" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

All I keep getting in return is no file uploaded, even if I take the testmode out it still does it.
The website is not very helpful http://imagezilla.net/api-docs.php
Any help would be Great. Jamie

Comment: Try setting the correct `enctype` for the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have no experience of working with Imagezilla, I suspect that you need to correctly set the `enctype` of your form:

```
<form action="http://imagezilla.net/api.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="passwordmd5" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="testmode" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```